# Run EC2 Command from a different website hosting platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, namecheap

I'm new to EC2 and most website hosting stuff in general. Throwing myself in the deep end, I guess.

I have a free micro instance of EC2 running and I git pulled a little program I have. After some setup stuff that program runs perfectly.

I also have a website hosted by namecheap. It isn't much but whatever, it's there.

I want to have a button on my website that will run the program on my EC2 instance. It looks like I need some kind of AWS Lambda function, or their gateway api, or something, but as I said, new to this stuff. Confused. Where should I start? I saw something about hosting through AWS as well, but it looks like that would mean a lot more management needs to be done by me that namecheap does for me.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your goal is not simple if all of this is new to you. Since you have an EC2 micro instance, I will assume it is running Linux. To run a program remotely you can use SSH or create a REST API. Since you mentioned "website button", that limits you to calling a REST endpoint. Google search as others have already tackled this problem.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, I appreciate the help. Sounds like I've got some work to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you have 2 viable options:

First, running a simple server on the instance and make REST calls to it.  Second, connect with SSH or AWS SSM to the instance and run the command directly.

Depending on the situation, you need to decide which option is better for you.

For the first option, I would recommend you try running a simple server (like [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/), or whatever) and send POST call to it using the button on your site.
When handling the call in the server, run the application locally.

For the second option, it can be trickier but essentially you would want to SSH to EC2 instances via AWS Lambda.

Nevertheless, you will need to configure the security group for that instance and open some ports to be able to connect remotely.

[SSH(22)](http://%5BHTTPS/HTTP%5D%5B2%5D)
[HTTPS/HTTP(80/443)](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/)

Probably there are more ways to do it. so feel free to investigate more.

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation. Seems lame for my own post. Thanks for the help! I'll check these out!

Comment: @Elkelthen - you should be able to click to accept this answer.

Comment: Entirely correct! I don't use this enough. Thanks for the tip!